# javascript convert from epoch string to Date object

Tags: javascript, datetime

```
var myDate = new Date();
var epoch = myDate.getTime(); //1318023197289 number of ms since epoch
var unixEpoch = Math.round(epoch/1000)
```

1. How do you convert `epoch` back to a Date object?
2. Can you also convert unixEpoch back to a Date object?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

```
var date = new Date(1318023197289);
```

And, since unixEpoch is simply epoch / 1000, you can similarly multiply the argument in the constructor by 1000.

Comment: thanks for quick response. In your example `date` is a number `(typeof date == 'number')` but I'm looking to reconstruct a Date Object.

Comment: Which browser are you using? typeof date gives me 'object'.  Also, JavaScript does not have a date 'type', it's just an object.

Comment: I should say that typeof date gives me 'object' in Chrome 14, Win7

Comment: It looks like you updated your answer while I was typing my first comment. Works now thanks :)