# Cross-Origin Request Blocked: Multiple API; need to aggregate data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, weather-api

Objective: Get precipIntensity for several days from at least 3 API.
Main issue: Cross-Origin Request Blocked, causing data to be undefined. What is a cross-origin request and how might I resolve this issue that interferes with the If() statement and gathering the collected JSON data into aggregates for mean precip?
**Updated Solution:**

```
    //Get the back dated times and current in UNIX, 
   //later make a lookup that gives datediff from current date and user's date and adjust index i condition to equal exact days.
            var totalPrecipSinceDate;
            var threeDayAPITimes = [];

        for (var i = 0; i <= 2; i++) //place user userData-1 where i <= input
    {
        var myDate = new Date(); //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7693170/javascript-convert-from-epoch-string-to-date-object
        var epoch = myDate.getTime(); 
        var unixEpoch = Math.round(epoch/1000)
        threeDayAPITimes[i] = Math.round(unixEpoch - (86400 * i));

    }
    //Plan to convert UNIX dates to display

    //List of locations: LATITUDE,LONGITUDE
    var locations = ["46.3494,-85.5083"]

    //setup a server-side proxy which would hide the API key from the client side
    var currentAPIKey ="privateKey"; //gets an APIkey from user input.



var listAPIs = "";

$.each(threeDayAPITimes, function(i, time) {
    var darkForecastAPI= "https://api.forecast.io/forecast/" + currentAPIKey + "/" + locations + "," + time +"?callback=?"; 
     $.getJSON(darkForecastAPI, {
        tags: "WxAPI[" + i + "]",  //Is this tag the name of each JSON page? I tried to index it incase this is how to refer to the JSON formatted code from the APIs.
        tagmode: "any",
        format: "json"
    }, function(result) {
        // Process the result object    
        var eachPrecipSum = 0;
    if(result.currently.precipIntensity >=0 && result.currently.precipType == "rain")
        {
            $.each(result, function() {
              eachPrecipSum += (this.currently.precipIntensity);
              totalPrecipSinceDate += eachPrecipSum ;  ///Write mean precip
                        alert(eachPrecipSum );
        });

    }   
});
});
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: do you have access to your web server configuration? If so, the fix is really easy. If not, then you will **have** to use a server side language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Cross-Origin Request is when you're making a request to another domain. To protect the user, that's not allowed by default. Browsers work on the same origin policy. This means that you can only make requests on the same domain.

*You* can't solve the Cross Origin Request problem. The owner of forecast.Io would have to authorize your domain with an HTTP header. I'm guessing they're not going to do that. Basically CORS gives the source control over who can use the API, not the consumer.

What you're best bet is likely to be is to work around the limitation. You will need to use JSONP. They support this but note this very wise caution in their [documentation](https://developer.forecast.io/docs/v2):
*Return the API response as JSONP. Please use caution when using this, since exposing your API key to the public is a security hazard and, if abused, will result in the revokation of your API key. However, if developing a personal- or internal-use app, this is a convenient method of doing so.*

To enable JSONP, simply put ?callback=? As the query string of your URL. This will make jQuery setup JSONP. In your example you'd do this anywhere you build the URL, so here:

```
var darkForecastAPI= "https://api.forecast.io/forecast/" + currentAPIKey + "/" + locations + "," + time +"?callback=?";
```

However, as they mention, your API key is exposed so be careful. If possible, make a server-side web service on your server that acts as a proxy between your JavaScript and their API. Not sure if that is possible but on their site they provide one written in PHP and you could write one in any language fairly easily.

Let me also give you a little background on JSONP since this is probably the first time you've heard of it. There are risks. Unlike JSON which returns objects, JSONP actually calls a JS function and executes code directly. That means if there is a malicious site, it could cause damage. I wouldn't worry too much about forecast.Io, but if it's someshadyrussianmp3site I'd be careful! The way it works is it injects a `<script src="http://forecast.io/blah/blah/blah/?callback=jquery_12345" ></script>` tag in your page. Script tags don't have the same origin restriction. That file basically wraps a JSON object into a call to jquery_12345 which jQuery abstracts for you so it works like normal. The other downside, other than security, is there is no good way to detect failure. JQuery will help by having a timeout that it can use to "assume" a failure, but you won't get a 500 error or anything like you would with true JSON.

Comment: I changed the API key before I posted. To set a better example I substituted a privateAPIKey string in the variable.

Comment: where exactly would this statement ?callback=? go in the code? or at least point to the line to add it, I am not certain.

Comment: Sure, `var darkForecastAPI= "https://api.forecast.io/forecast/" + currentAPIKey + "/" + locations + "," + time +"?callback=?";` It is a query string parameter.

Comment: By the way the point about the API key is not that you'd be posting it on stackoverflow, it becomes public because all I have to do is view source on your webpage and I can steal it. Then I could abuse your API key and get you banned from forecast.Io. That's why they recommend you setup a server-side proxy which would hide the API key from the client side.

Comment: Great and thank you for your help and wisdom. The cross-origin error is gone but now I got a little debug issue. How would you ask with an && statement both conditions to be true in a long JSON script with current Wx and it has to be read "rain"? I am getting an undefined return in firebug but the code seems to make sense in a C# sort of context (which I am more familiar with.)

Comment: You think the APIkey is visible then on the javascript code? I have not implemented it on a server yet if I do. For now its a private calculator. Although someone could have abused what I got now- but I reset it. (swoo)

Comment: The API key would be visible on the source, and also in the browser's network monitor feature. As for your undefined variable question, can you explain more? Not sure I follow. && works the same way in JavaScript as it does in C#

Comment: The JSON looks like this:     "currently": {
        "time": 1429545600,
        "summary": "Mostly Cloudy",
        "icon": "partly-cloudy-day",
        "precipIntensity": 0.0076,
        "precipProbability": 0.32,
        "precipType": "rain",
        "temperature": 42.33,
        "apparentTemperature": 42.33,
        "dewPoint": 39.47,
        "humidity": 0.9,
        "windSpeed": 0.26,
        "windBearing": 143,
        "visibility": 7.19,
        "cloudCover": 0.74,
        "pressure": 984.94,
        "ozone": 338.05
    },

Comment: There can be more than one of these tags for rain and precipIntensity, especially if I implement the hourly forecast

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76745/discussion-between-dman2306-and-safron6).

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to invoke a URL served by a domain api.forecast.io which is different from the domain your javascript code originated from, hence it is a cross domain request.

Other domain does not support CORS. This can be resolved by adding ACAO header by other domain.

[CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)

Comment: Not familiar with the ACAO header, explain more please what you are thinking about the solution.

Comment: @safron6 that's not a solution because the ACAO header has to be added on the forecast.Io side, not yours. They're not going to do that. See my answer below, it might point you in the right direction. If you have further questions I'd be happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making the Ajax call in the client side JavaScript, you can do it in your server side code and not have to deal with CORS. Google: CORS proxy {your server side language}